# Joined select assuming criteria given in the next record

Tags: sql, inner-join, criteria

I have a SQL Server 2012 table with hundreds thousands rows of geology data *(please refer to the screenshot below)*. These are records of `gCode`s for different `CountryID`s.

I need a joined-select of all `gCode`s for `CountryID = 112` assuming the following criteria:

- `Xc` for CountryID=61 is significantly greater than `Xm`. At least 200%
- `Xm` and `Xc` for CountryID=112 is equal.

There are two examples on the screenshot provided. In both cases:

- `Xm = Xc = 1395` for CountryID=112
- For CountryID=61 `Xc` is significantly greater than `Xm` for the same `gCode`

Which means that I want these two records into the recordset.

I understand that my query must somehow do the `inner join ... on gCode` within the same table but so far, I have no idea how to write the query. I wrote some queries but it did not bring the desired result.

[image: Example from my table]

Comment: The format of your question makes it very hard to see and understand what you are doing.  Instead show sample input and output along with the logic to get to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a direct translation into SQL:

```
with cte1 as
 ( select gCode 
   from tab
   where CountryID = 112
     and xm = xc -- Xm and Xc for CountryID=112 is equal.
 ),
cte2 
 ( select gCode 
   from tab
   where CountryID = 61
     and xc/xm >= 3 -- Xc for CountryID=61 is significantly greater than Xm. At least 200%
 )
select cte1.gCode
from cte1
join cte2
on cte1.gCode = cte2.gCode
```

I would prefer a correlated subquery:

```
select gCode 
from tab as t1
where CountryID = 112
and xm = xc -- Xm and Xc for CountryID=112 is equal.
and exists
 ( select * 
   from tab as t2
   where t2.gCode = t1.gCode
     and CountryID = 61
     and xc/xm >= 3 -- Xc for CountryID=61 is significantly greater
 )
```

Comment: Correlated query looks very nice to me. I changed `...where (t2.gCode = t1.gCode) and (t2.CountryID = 61) and (xc/xm >= 3)` and it works just perfect! Exactly what I need. Vielen Dank! :)

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown: Of course, I fixed both queries, thanks, gern geschehen :)